# How to handle empty response using Alamofire and Combine?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, combine

I am making a post request, which has an empty response

```
AF.request(URL(string: "some url")!, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil)
    .validate()
    .publishDecodable(type: T.self)
    .value()
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
```

where T is

`struct EmptyResponse: Codable {}`

and I am having this error "Response could not be serialized, input data was nil or zero length."
How do I handle a post request with an empty response using Alamofire and Combine?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This error occurs when your backend returns no data but does not return an appropriate HTTP response code (204 or 205). If this is expected behavior for your backend, you can add your response code to the list of acceptable empty response codes when you set up the publisher: `.publishDecodable(T.self, emptyResponseCodes: [200]`. This also requires `T` to either conform to Alamofire's `EmptyResponse` protocol, or for you to expect Alamofire's `Empty` type as the response.

Comment: Thanks, I guess it's "emptyResponseCodes: [200]", worked this way.

Comment: I'm having hard time with defining Combine response as Empty type                              -> AnyPublisher<Empty, AFError>   don't work 'Empty is ambiguous for type lookup

Comment: My backend sends no content and 204 code I'm getting Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.inputDataNilOrZeroLength

Comment: @LukaszD try Alamofire.Empty

Answer (score 5):

Found answer somewhere else but it's useful here. Made empty object like that:

```
struct EmptyEntity: Codable, EmptyResponse {
    
    static func emptyValue() -> EmptyEntity {
        return EmptyEntity.init()
    }
}
```

And return publisher like so:

```
-> AnyPublisher<EmptyEntity, AFError>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
AF.request(UrlUtils.base_url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding.default, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response:AFDataResponse<Any>) in
                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(_):
                    // this case handles http response code 200, so it will be a successful response
                    break
                case .failure(_): 
                    break
                }
            }
```

Comment: This answer does not address the Combine part of the question; specifically how to handle empty responses when using `.publishDecodable(...)`